# Can I create a cross-platform wxPython application that uses Flash embeds?

Tags: python, flash, wxpython

I'm considering creating a wxPython application that I'll deploy for Windows and OSX. I want to include Flash objects like YouTube embeds and Twitch.tv embeds in the application. Is that possible? Are there any resources out there that addresses the issue?

Comment: Maybe try the html rendering widget `wx.html2.WebView`? I haven't used this myself and I do not know if it also handles flash.

Comment: @HansThen: I tried it and it worked in Windows. I'll test it in OSX when I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the WebView widget that was mentioned or download the separate webkit port and try that (search the wxPython mailing list for a link to that). Otherwise, the only truly supported wxPython widget that does this is "ActiveX_FlashWindow" and I'm pretty sure that's Windows-only.